# DispatcherTimer not working in uwp app

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

I have an UWP app running on my Raspberry Pi (Windows 10 IoT Core). I need a time that I can start, stop, check if its running and execute something after. The `DispatcherTimer` seemed to be a perfect fit, if it would run...

This is my code:

```
    public override void Run()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("test1");

        SenseHat.Display.Clear();

        Debug.WriteLine("test2");

        _currentDirection = Direction.East;

        updatePositionTimer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500) };

        Debug.WriteLine("test3");

        updatePositionTimer.Tick += timer_Tick;

        Debug.WriteLine("test4");
```

I have added the `Writelines` to see at what line the error occurs. In the console I can see `test1` and `test2` so the error has to occur where the `DispatcherTimer` is made. I do not see any error or exception besides:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in [program name].exe

I have done some research and found an other timer, [ThreadPoolTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPoolTimer), but this A) does not work as stated and B) does not meet my requirements.

What would be a solution to my problem?

**EDIT**

This is what I want to do with the timer:

```
while (true)
{
    if (!updatePositionTimer.IsEnabled)
    {
        updatePositionTimer.Start();
    }

    Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2));
}
```

Comment: `DispatcherTimer` is for running code that runs in the UI, if there is no UI, it will throw an exception when it tries to invoke the code on the UI thread. You should be able to use a `System.Threading.Timer`, you can stop it by changing the interval/delay to `Timeout.Infinite`.

Comment: Hi, I have made an update to my question. Is that posible with the `System.Threading.Timer`?

Comment: It is difficult to determine if the timer is stopped, but you could also use [System.Timers.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2) if you want something closer to the dispatcher timer.

Comment: I do not have `System.Timers`, but I think I might be able to make the `System.Threading.Timer` work.

Comment: Okay, I have got it to work with the System.Threading.Timer! If you submit it as an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: @LuukWuijster You can show how you solved the problem and add an answer. It will be helpful for others are searching on this. Thanks.